# The disjoint union of metrizable spaces is metrizable.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\{X\}_{\alpha\in\mathscr{A}}$ be a collection of metrizable spaces and consider their disjoint union
> $$X:=\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in\mathscr{A}}X_{\alpha}.$$
> Show that $X$ is metrizable.

Not sure where to begin. I figured some employment of a theorem is need; such as, the Urysohn Metrization Theorem, but I don't see how that could be used. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if a space is metrizable, then it is metrizable by a metric that takes values in $[0, 1]$. Now suppose each of your spaces $X_\alpha$ is equipped with such a metric...

Comment: If it's just a disjoint *union*, the statement is wrong: there are non-metrizable spaces consisting of a disjoint union of two discrete spaces. The metrizable subspaces have to be open, i.e. the space is their *sum*.